# Convert value of one df based on second df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, for-loop

I have 2 dataframe df1 and df2.  df1 have 2 specific columns:

```
                                                    Code: H4, H5. 
                                                    Cat: 010121, 010190, 345654... 
                                                    and other variables too
```

df2 has 2 columns: **V17** & **V02**. Both of these columns contains values, but V17 contains same values as **Cat** column in df1, but in different order.

```
V17       v02
010121    010110
010129    010190
010130    010190
.....     .....
```

What I need is following: if specific row of **df1$code**= H5, the observed value in **Cat** column must be changed by corresponding value in **V02**

For instance I we this kind of row in df1:

```
Code     Cat        ...
H4       010121     ...
```

010121 value must be change by 010110 (according to **V02**)

```
V17       v02
010121    010110
```

and I need all these for the rest of dataframe like a loop function.
Hope that's not too complicate.

Comment: I suspect this is a join/merge operation, and therefore can be resolved using https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272. It's hard to tell without a reproducible question though. If the above do not answer your issue, please use `dput(.)` to share your data, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would proceed:

1. Merge the table based on the common column (I'm assuming here that you Cat and V17 columns contain unique values?)

`df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Cat", by.y = "V17")`

2. Assign to Cat the value of V02 if Code = H5

`df3$Cat <- ifelse(df3$Code == "H5", df3$V02, df3$Cat)`

I cannot test the code without a reproducible example but hopefully this can help somehow.

Good luck !